# (study indicators) how to check the chart symbol to apply formulas

Tags: pine-script

I'm creating a personal indicator but I can't find the code that allows me to identify the symbol and choose it automatically.

now I have to choose the symbol in manual

```
method = input(title='Method (1 US 2 JPM 3  AAPL 4  TSLA 5  AMD 6   BAC 7   BABA 8  EEM 9   IWM 10  EFA 11  QQQ 12  HYG 13  FXI 14  EWZ 15  HG 16   SI 17   GDX 18  GC 19   NG 20   CL 21   HE 22   LE 23   CC 24   ZC 25   ZS 26   ZW 27   AUD/USD 28  JPY/USD 29  EUR/USD  30 GBP/USD ):', type=integer, defval=1, minval=0, maxval=30)

method_Hig = method == 0 ? -3 :

  method == 1 ? 158.00 :
  method == 2 ? 115.00 :
  method == 3 ? 182.50 :
  method == 4 ? 240.00 :
  method == 5 ? 36.00 :
  method == 6 ? 31.00 :
  na
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

The `ticker` [built-in variable](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#var_ticker) returns the symbol currently selected.

It is usually better to use `tickerid` [built-in variable](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#var_tickerid) since it also includes the prefix for the exchange.

If this doesn't answer your question please feel free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56495101/edit) your question going a bit more in detail on why you want to do this - I'll be happy to help and update my answer.

Comment: Hi @Sergio T. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks, I have solved

```
method_TC = ticker

method_T2 = method_TC == 'JPM' ? 2 :
    method_TC == 'ZB1!' ? 1 :
    method_TC == 'AAPL' ? 3 :
   ........ 
   na


  method=method_T2

method_Hig = method == 0 ? -3 :
    method == 1?158.00 :
    method == 2?115.00 :
    method == 3?182.50 :
    .......
    na
```